# Simple Arithmetic Puzzle 2. Or is it?

Tags: mathematics

A second maths puzzle!

> $$\begin{align}0+0&=0\\1+1&=1\\2+2&=2\\12.2+6&=20\\12.3+6&=21\\9+(-3.2)&=-10\\7+(-1.1)&=-3\\0.95+(-0.95)&=-1\\e^\pi+(-\pi)&=\quad?\end{align}$$

Can you find the value of the question mark?

**HINT 1:**

> GIF

**HINT 2:**

> SQRT

**HINT 3:**

> X

**HINT 4:**

> ANS = ☐

Not very simple this time I suppose :)

Comment: You could still title it "e to the pi minus pi" and submit it to the FTC (albeit late) :P https://www.xkcd.com/217/

Comment: e^π+(−π) = 19.9990999792

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule is

> $a$ **+** $b :=  \lfloor \sqrt{a} * b \rfloor $

And so the answer is

> $e^\pi$ **+** $(-\pi) := \lfloor \sqrt{e^\pi} * (-\pi) \rfloor = \lfloor -15.11256\ldots \rfloor = -16$

Examples

$12.2 + 6$

> $\lfloor \sqrt{12.2} * 6 \rfloor = \lfloor 3.4928\ldots * 6 \rfloor = \lfloor 20.957\ldots \rfloor = 20$

$12.3 + 6$

> $\lfloor \sqrt{12.3} * 6 \rfloor = \lfloor 3.5071\ldots * 6 \rfloor = \lfloor 21.042\ldots \rfloor = 21$

$7 + (-1.1)$

> $\lfloor \sqrt{7} * (-1.1) \rfloor = \lfloor 2.6457\ldots * (-1.1) \rfloor = \lfloor -2.9103\ldots \rfloor = -3$

Hints

> Hints 2,3 and 4 pretty much spell out the procedure. Hint 1 is the acronym GIF which, in this particular case, stands for Greatest Integer Function. I have used the floor function notation which is equivalent.